# How to use custom Spring scope with unit tests (SpringJUnit4ClassRunner)

Tags: java, spring, junit, junit4

I am using JUnit tests with Spring configuration defined in a class annotated with `@Configuration` in my JUnit Test. The tests looks like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyConfiguration.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class SomeIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyConfiguration myConfiguration;

    @Test
    public void someTest() throws Exception {
       myConfiguration.myBean();
    }
}
```

In `MyConfiguration`, I would like to use Spring scope `SimpleThreadScope`:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Scope("thread")
    public MyBean myBean() {
        return new MyBean();
    }
}
```

When I run the test, the scope is not registered, though. I get

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope 'thread'
```

I am aware how a custom scope can be registered programatically:
`context.getBeanFactory().registerScope("thread", new SimpleThreadScope());`
and I would like to avoid using XML Spring configuration.

Is there any way, how can I register the custom scope in the unit test?

Comment: have you solved this issue? if yes, how did you solve it?

Comment: Hi, I have found a pretty elegant solution, but I kind of stashed it somewhere and cannot find it now (the code has been refactored since) :). Let me look for it a little longer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this execution listener:

```
public class WebContextTestExecutionListener extends
            AbstractTestExecutionListener {

        @Override
        public void prepareTestInstance(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {

            if (testContext.getApplicationContext() instanceof GenericApplicationContext) {
                GenericApplicationContext context = (GenericApplicationContext) testContext.getApplicationContext();
                ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = context
                        .getBeanFactory();
                Scope requestScope = new SimpleThreadScope();
                beanFactory.registerScope("request", requestScope);
                Scope sessionScope = new SimpleThreadScope();
                beanFactory.registerScope("session", sessionScope);
                Scope threadScope= new SimpleThreadScope();
                beanFactory.registerScope("thread", threadScope);
            }
        }
    }
```

in the test you can put this

```
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = MyConfiguration.class})
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
    @TestExecutionListeners( { WebContextTestExecutionListener.class})
    public class UserSpringIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserBean userBean;

    //All the test methods
    }
```